Measurability of $\int_\Omega u(t,x)\;dx$ given $t \mapsto u(t,x)$ is measurable
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain and consider a function $u\colon [0,T] \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that
$$F(t) := \int_\Omega u(t,x)\;dx$$ exists for all $t \in [0,T]$. If I know that $t \mapsto u(t,x)$ is measurable for almost all $x$, does it follow that $F$ is a measurable function? Or which conditions would I need on $u$ for that?

$\iint_{[0,T]\times\Omega}|u(t,x)|,\mathrm dt,\mathrm dx<\infty$ is a sufficient condition (by Fubini's theorem).

At least when the integrand $u$ is continuous and dominated by an $L^1$ function, then $F$ is continuous, so measurable.
